# How can I give Unique ID's while building HTML with JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I'm trying to build store functionality and what I would like to do is be able to save the information of each object to storage by pressing the "add to cart" button on the page. I'm wondering how I could go about creating unique ID's for each "add to cart" button while using a for loop to create more than one item/feature box like below?

```
 // temporary javascript thingy while we build the remove catalogs
 var popularItems =  
      [
           {
               "itemImageSrc" : "./images/StoreProducts/StrawberryPi2ModelB.jpg",
               "itemImageAlt" : "placeholder",
               "itemDescription" : "<p> Strawberry Pi 3 Model B </p>",
               "itemPrice" : "<p>$49.95</p>",
               "itemPopular" : "true"
           },
           {
               "itemImageSrc" : "./images/StoreProducts/StrawberryPiZero.jpg",
               "itemImageAlt" : "placeholder",
               "itemDescription" : "<p> Strawberry Pi Zero </p>",
               "itemPrice" : "<p>$29.95</p>",
               "itemPopular" : "true"
           },
           {
               "itemImageSrc" : "./images/StoreProducts/StrawberryPiCase.jpg",
               "itemImageAlt" : "placeholder",
               "itemDescription" : "<p> Strawberry Pi Case </p>",
               "itemPrice" : "<p>$10.95</p>",
               "itemPopular" : "true"
           },
           {
               "itemImageSrc" : "./images/StoreProducts/placeholder.png",
               "itemImageAlt" : "placeholder",
               "itemDescription" : "<p> Strawberry Pi Extension Kit </p>",
               "itemPrice" : "<p>$149.95</p>",
               "itemPopular" : "false"
           }
      ];

document.write( '<div class="feature-container">' );

for ( var i = 0; i < popularItems.length; i++) {

if ( popularItems[i].itemPopular == "true" ) {

document.writeln('<div class="feature-box">');
document.write('<img src="');
document.writeln(popularItems[i].itemImageSrc);
document.write('" alt="');
    document.write(popularItems[i].itemImageAlt);
document.writeln('">');

document.write('<div class="feature-box-model"  id="var i">');
document.write(popularItems[i].itemDescription);
document.writeln('</div>');

document.write('<div class="feature-box-price">');
document.write(popularItems[i].itemPrice);
document.writeln('</div>');

document.writeln('<FORM>');
    document.writeln('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Add To Cart" onclick="saveData()" id="unique">');
document.writeln('</FORM>');
document.writeln('</div>');

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify this line:

```js
document.writeln('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Add To Cart" onclick="saveData()" id="unique">');
```

to be:

```js
document.writeln('<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Add To Cart" onclick="saveData()" id="item_'+i+'">');
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that I just have document.writeIn(");

Comment: edited my answer, it is the part where you want the unique identifier.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you p.phresh! This works exactly how I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the obvious

```
`for( let =0; i<n; i++ ){
   let key = 'key_'+i;
   ....
 }'
```

doesn't meet your needs?

Then a simple approach might be something like:

```
`key = 'key_'+Math.random().toString().slice(2);`
`// => "key_21542707442294184"`
```

Comment: Or use the array index `i` like so: `id="item"+i` (`id="item1"`, `id=item2` ...)

Comment: The first one doesn't work unless I tried it incorrectly. that second part I don't understand so I'll have to do some more research on the key and math random stuff. and Chrki, I thought that would work too but I can't find a way that actually evaluates the "i" to the number that the for loop is using. It just takes it literally.